# Getting Only Zeros from Model.Predict() When Using Individual Data Points But Getting both 1's and 0's when Using Entire Test Dataset

Tags: python, machine-learning, keras, deep-learning, neural-network

We trained a binary classification nn with ~90% accuracy/~20% loss. When we use the model by calling model.predict() function with the testing data (which is 20% of our entire dataset), we get a relatively even distribution of 1's and 0's. But when we input individual points from the testing data as a numpy array, we only get 0's regardless of shuffling or not. Can anyone help us explain why we are getting this behavior?

When we use X_test (from the split above) instead of `dummyTest`, `binary_prediction` equals 1 for the respective data point array from `dummyTest`), but when we use `dummyTest`'s data individually, `binary_prediction` only equals 0.

Full Code Shown Below:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from pandas.plotting import scatter_matrix
from sklearn import model_selection
from keras.utils.np_utils import to_categorical
from keras.models import Sequential
from keras.layers import Dense
from tensorflow.keras.optimizers import Adam
from keras.layers import Dropout
import os

full_dataset = pd.read_csv('noQMarkDataset.csv')
data = full_dataset[~full_dataset.isin(['?'])]
data = data.dropna(axis=0)
data = data.apply(pd.to_numeric)

X = np.array(data.drop(['target'], 1))
y = np.array(data['target'])

mean = X.mean(axis=0)
X -= mean
std = X.std(axis=0)
X /= std

X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = model_selection.train_test_split(X, y, random_state = 0, test_size = 0.2, shuffle=False)  #stratify = y

# convert data to categorical labels
Y_train = to_categorical(y_train, num_classes=None)
Y_test = to_categorical(y_test, num_classes=None)

Y_train_binary = y_train.copy()
Y_test_binary = y_test.copy()

Y_train_binary[Y_train_binary > 0] = 1
Y_test_binary[Y_test_binary > 0] = 1

def create_binary_model():
    model = Sequential()
    model.add(Dense(16, input_dim=7,  activation='relu')) # prev input_dim =1 3
    model.add(Dropout(0.25))
    model.add(Dense(16,  activation = 'relu'))
    model.add(Dropout(0.25))
    model.add(Dense(16))
    model.add(Dropout(0.25))
    model.add(Dense(12, activation = 'relu'))
    model.add(Dense(12, activation = 'relu'))
    model.add(Dropout(0.25))
    model.add(Dense(8,  activation='relu'))
    model.add(Dropout(0.25))
    model.add(Dense(1, activation='sigmoid'))

    adam = Adam(lr=0.001)
    model.compile(loss='binary_crossentropy', optimizer='rmsprop', metrics=['accuracy'])       #optimizer = 'rmsprop'  previously 
    
    return model

binary_model = create_binary_model()
history=binary_model.fit(X_train, Y_train_binary, validation_data=(X_test, Y_test_binary), epochs=130, batch_size=15)   #epochs = 130, batch_size = 20 previously (best)

plt.plot(history.history['accuracy'])
plt.plot(history.history['val_accuracy'])
plt.title('Model Accuracy')
plt.ylabel('accuracy')
plt.xlabel('epoch')
plt.legend(['train', 'test'])
plt.show()

plt.plot(history.history['loss'])
plt.plot(history.history['val_loss'])
plt.title('Model Loss')
plt.ylabel('loss')
plt.xlabel('epoch')
plt.legend(['train', 'test'])
plt.show()

from sklearn.metrics import classification_report, accuracy_score
dummyTest = np.array([[67.0,1.0,4.0,0.0,2.0,129.0,2.0]])
binary_pred = np.round(binary_model.predict(dummyTest)).astype(int) 
#binary_pred = np.round(binary_model.predict(X_test)).astype(int)
print(f"Binary Pred: {binary_pred}")

binary_model.save(os.path.join(".", "test_model.h5"))

#after loading
from tensorflow.keras.models import load_model
model2 = load_model(os.path.join(".", "test_model.h5"))
binary_pred2 = np.round(binary_model.predict(dummyTest)).astype(int) 
#binary_pred2 = np.round(binary_model.predict(X_test)).astype(int)
print(f"Binary Pred2 after load: {binary_pred2}")
```

Full Dataset Shown Below

```
age,sex,cp,fbs,restecg,thalach,ca,target
63.0,1.0,1.0,1.0,2.0,150.0,0.0,0
67.0,1.0,4.0,0.0,2.0,108.0,3.0,2
67.0,1.0,4.0,0.0,2.0,129.0,2.0,1
37.0,1.0,3.0,0.0,0.0,187.0,0.0,0
41.0,0.0,2.0,0.0,2.0,172.0,0.0,0
56.0,1.0,2.0,0.0,0.0,178.0,0.0,0
62.0,0.0,4.0,0.0,2.0,160.0,2.0,3
57.0,0.0,4.0,0.0,0.0,163.0,0.0,0
63.0,1.0,4.0,0.0,2.0,147.0,1.0,2
53.0,1.0,4.0,1.0,2.0,155.0,0.0,1
57.0,1.0,4.0,0.0,0.0,148.0,0.0,0
56.0,0.0,2.0,0.0,2.0,153.0,0.0,0
56.0,1.0,3.0,1.0,2.0,142.0,1.0,2
44.0,1.0,2.0,0.0,0.0,173.0,0.0,0
52.0,1.0,3.0,1.0,0.0,162.0,0.0,0
57.0,1.0,3.0,0.0,0.0,174.0,0.0,0
48.0,1.0,2.0,0.0,0.0,168.0,0.0,1
54.0,1.0,4.0,0.0,0.0,160.0,0.0,0
48.0,0.0,3.0,0.0,0.0,139.0,0.0,0
49.0,1.0,2.0,0.0,0.0,171.0,0.0,0
64.0,1.0,1.0,0.0,2.0,144.0,0.0,0
58.0,0.0,1.0,1.0,2.0,162.0,0.0,0
58.0,1.0,2.0,0.0,2.0,160.0,0.0,1
58.0,1.0,3.0,0.0,2.0,173.0,2.0,3
60.0,1.0,4.0,0.0,2.0,132.0,2.0,4
50.0,0.0,3.0,0.0,0.0,158.0,0.0,0
58.0,0.0,3.0,0.0,0.0,172.0,0.0,0
66.0,0.0,1.0,0.0,0.0,114.0,0.0,0
43.0,1.0,4.0,0.0,0.0,171.0,0.0,0
40.0,1.0,4.0,0.0,2.0,114.0,0.0,3
69.0,0.0,1.0,0.0,0.0,151.0,2.0,0
60.0,1.0,4.0,1.0,0.0,160.0,2.0,2
64.0,1.0,3.0,0.0,0.0,158.0,0.0,1
59.0,1.0,4.0,0.0,0.0,161.0,0.0,0
44.0,1.0,3.0,0.0,0.0,179.0,0.0,0
42.0,1.0,4.0,0.0,0.0,178.0,0.0,0
43.0,1.0,4.0,0.0,2.0,120.0,0.0,3
57.0,1.0,4.0,0.0,2.0,112.0,1.0,1
55.0,1.0,4.0,0.0,0.0,132.0,1.0,3
61.0,1.0,3.0,1.0,0.0,137.0,0.0,0
65.0,0.0,4.0,0.0,2.0,114.0,3.0,4
40.0,1.0,1.0,0.0,0.0,178.0,0.0,0
71.0,0.0,2.0,0.0,0.0,162.0,2.0,0
59.0,1.0,3.0,1.0,0.0,157.0,0.0,0
61.0,0.0,4.0,0.0,2.0,169.0,0.0,1
58.0,1.0,3.0,0.0,2.0,165.0,1.0,4
51.0,1.0,3.0,0.0,0.0,123.0,0.0,0
50.0,1.0,4.0,0.0,2.0,128.0,0.0,4
65.0,0.0,3.0,1.0,2.0,157.0,1.0,0
53.0,1.0,3.0,1.0,2.0,152.0,0.0,0
41.0,0.0,2.0,0.0,0.0,168.0,1.0,0
65.0,1.0,4.0,0.0,0.0,140.0,0.0,0
44.0,1.0,4.0,0.0,2.0,153.0,1.0,2
44.0,1.0,2.0,0.0,2.0,188.0,0.0,0
60.0,1.0,4.0,0.0,0.0,144.0,1.0,1
54.0,1.0,4.0,0.0,2.0,109.0,1.0,1
50.0,1.0,3.0,0.0,0.0,163.0,1.0,1
41.0,1.0,4.0,0.0,2.0,158.0,0.0,1
54.0,1.0,3.0,0.0,2.0,152.0,1.0,0
51.0,1.0,1.0,0.0,2.0,125.0,1.0,0
51.0,0.0,4.0,0.0,0.0,142.0,0.0,2
46.0,0.0,3.0,0.0,2.0,160.0,0.0,0
58.0,1.0,4.0,0.0,2.0,131.0,3.0,1
54.0,0.0,3.0,1.0,0.0,170.0,0.0,0
54.0,1.0,4.0,0.0,0.0,113.0,1.0,2
60.0,1.0,4.0,0.0,2.0,142.0,2.0,2
60.0,1.0,3.0,0.0,2.0,155.0,0.0,1
54.0,1.0,3.0,0.0,2.0,165.0,0.0,0
59.0,1.0,4.0,0.0,2.0,140.0,0.0,2
46.0,1.0,3.0,0.0,0.0,147.0,0.0,1
65.0,0.0,3.0,0.0,0.0,148.0,0.0,0
67.0,1.0,4.0,1.0,0.0,163.0,2.0,3
62.0,1.0,4.0,0.0,0.0,99.0,2.0,1
65.0,1.0,4.0,0.0,2.0,158.0,2.0,1
44.0,1.0,4.0,0.0,2.0,177.0,1.0,1
65.0,0.0,3.0,0.0,2.0,151.0,0.0,0
60.0,1.0,4.0,0.0,2.0,141.0,1.0,1
51.0,0.0,3.0,0.0,2.0,142.0,1.0,0
48.0,1.0,2.0,0.0,2.0,180.0,0.0,0
58.0,1.0,4.0,0.0,2.0,111.0,0.0,3
45.0,1.0,4.0,0.0,2.0,148.0,0.0,0
53.0,0.0,4.0,0.0,2.0,143.0,0.0,0
39.0,1.0,3.0,0.0,2.0,182.0,0.0,0
68.0,1.0,3.0,1.0,2.0,150.0,0.0,3
52.0,1.0,2.0,0.0,0.0,172.0,0.0,0
44.0,1.0,3.0,0.0,2.0,180.0,0.0,0
47.0,1.0,3.0,0.0,2.0,156.0,0.0,0
53.0,0.0,3.0,0.0,2.0,115.0,0.0,0
53.0,0.0,4.0,0.0,2.0,160.0,0.0,0
51.0,0.0,3.0,0.0,2.0,149.0,0.0,0
66.0,1.0,4.0,0.0,2.0,151.0,0.0,0
62.0,0.0,4.0,0.0,2.0,145.0,3.0,3
62.0,1.0,3.0,0.0,0.0,146.0,3.0,0
44.0,0.0,3.0,0.0,0.0,175.0,0.0,0
63.0,0.0,3.0,0.0,2.0,172.0,0.0,0
52.0,1.0,4.0,0.0,0.0,161.0,1.0,1
59.0,1.0,4.0,0.0,2.0,142.0,1.0,2
60.0,0.0,4.0,0.0,2.0,157.0,2.0,3
52.0,1.0,2.0,0.0,0.0,158.0,1.0,0
48.0,1.0,4.0,0.0,2.0,186.0,0.0,0
45.0,1.0,4.0,0.0,2.0,185.0,0.0,0
34.0,1.0,1.0,0.0,2.0,174.0,0.0,0
57.0,0.0,4.0,0.0,2.0,159.0,1.0,0
71.0,0.0,3.0,1.0,2.0,130.0,1.0,0
49.0,1.0,3.0,0.0,0.0,139.0,3.0,3
54.0,1.0,2.0,0.0,0.0,156.0,0.0,0
59.0,1.0,4.0,0.0,0.0,162.0,1.0,2
57.0,1.0,3.0,0.0,2.0,150.0,1.0,1
61.0,1.0,4.0,0.0,0.0,140.0,1.0,2
39.0,1.0,4.0,0.0,0.0,140.0,0.0,3
61.0,0.0,4.0,0.0,2.0,146.0,0.0,1
56.0,1.0,4.0,1.0,2.0,144.0,1.0,1
52.0,1.0,1.0,0.0,2.0,190.0,0.0,0
43.0,0.0,4.0,1.0,2.0,136.0,0.0,2
62.0,0.0,3.0,0.0,0.0,97.0,1.0,2
41.0,1.0,2.0,0.0,0.0,132.0,0.0,0
58.0,1.0,3.0,1.0,2.0,165.0,0.0,0
35.0,0.0,4.0,0.0,0.0,182.0,0.0,0
63.0,1.0,4.0,1.0,2.0,132.0,3.0,3
65.0,1.0,4.0,0.0,2.0,127.0,1.0,2
48.0,1.0,4.0,1.0,2.0,150.0,2.0,3
63.0,0.0,4.0,0.0,2.0,154.0,3.0,4
51.0,1.0,3.0,0.0,0.0,143.0,0.0,0
55.0,1.0,4.0,0.0,0.0,111.0,0.0,3
65.0,1.0,1.0,1.0,2.0,174.0,1.0,1
45.0,0.0,2.0,0.0,2.0,175.0,0.0,0
56.0,0.0,4.0,1.0,2.0,133.0,2.0,3
54.0,1.0,4.0,0.0,0.0,126.0,1.0,3
44.0,1.0,2.0,0.0,0.0,170.0,0.0,0
62.0,0.0,4.0,0.0,0.0,163.0,0.0,0
54.0,1.0,3.0,0.0,2.0,147.0,0.0,0
51.0,1.0,3.0,0.0,0.0,154.0,1.0,0
29.0,1.0,2.0,0.0,2.0,202.0,0.0,0
51.0,1.0,4.0,0.0,2.0,186.0,0.0,0
43.0,0.0,3.0,0.0,0.0,165.0,0.0,0
55.0,0.0,2.0,0.0,2.0,161.0,0.0,0
70.0,1.0,4.0,0.0,0.0,125.0,0.0,4
62.0,1.0,2.0,0.0,2.0,103.0,1.0,3
35.0,1.0,4.0,0.0,0.0,130.0,0.0,1
51.0,1.0,3.0,1.0,2.0,166.0,0.0,0
59.0,1.0,2.0,0.0,0.0,164.0,0.0,0
59.0,1.0,1.0,0.0,2.0,159.0,0.0,1
52.0,1.0,2.0,1.0,0.0,184.0,0.0,0
64.0,1.0,3.0,0.0,0.0,131.0,0.0,1
58.0,1.0,3.0,0.0,2.0,154.0,0.0,0
47.0,1.0,3.0,0.0,0.0,152.0,0.0,1
57.0,1.0,4.0,1.0,2.0,124.0,3.0,4
41.0,1.0,3.0,0.0,0.0,179.0,0.0,0
45.0,1.0,2.0,0.0,2.0,170.0,0.0,0
60.0,0.0,3.0,0.0,0.0,160.0,1.0,0
52.0,1.0,1.0,1.0,0.0,178.0,0.0,0
42.0,0.0,4.0,0.0,2.0,122.0,0.0,0
67.0,0.0,3.0,0.0,2.0,160.0,0.0,0
55.0,1.0,4.0,0.0,2.0,145.0,1.0,4
64.0,1.0,4.0,0.0,2.0,96.0,1.0,3
70.0,1.0,4.0,0.0,2.0,109.0,3.0,1
51.0,1.0,4.0,0.0,0.0,173.0,0.0,1
58.0,1.0,4.0,0.0,2.0,171.0,2.0,1
60.0,1.0,4.0,0.0,2.0,170.0,2.0,2
68.0,1.0,3.0,0.0,0.0,151.0,1.0,0
46.0,1.0,2.0,1.0,0.0,156.0,0.0,0
77.0,1.0,4.0,0.0,2.0,162.0,3.0,4
54.0,0.0,3.0,0.0,0.0,158.0,0.0,0
58.0,0.0,4.0,0.0,2.0,122.0,0.0,0
48.0,1.0,3.0,1.0,0.0,175.0,2.0,0
57.0,1.0,4.0,0.0,0.0,168.0,0.0,0
54.0,0.0,2.0,1.0,2.0,159.0,1.0,0
35.0,1.0,4.0,0.0,2.0,156.0,0.0,1
45.0,0.0,2.0,0.0,0.0,138.0,0.0,0
70.0,1.0,3.0,0.0,0.0,112.0,1.0,3
53.0,1.0,4.0,0.0,2.0,111.0,0.0,0
59.0,0.0,4.0,0.0,0.0,143.0,0.0,1
62.0,0.0,4.0,0.0,2.0,157.0,0.0,0
64.0,1.0,4.0,0.0,2.0,132.0,2.0,4
57.0,1.0,4.0,0.0,0.0,88.0,1.0,1
52.0,1.0,4.0,1.0,0.0,147.0,3.0,0
56.0,1.0,4.0,0.0,2.0,105.0,1.0,1
43.0,1.0,3.0,0.0,0.0,162.0,1.0,0
53.0,1.0,3.0,1.0,2.0,173.0,3.0,0
48.0,1.0,4.0,0.0,2.0,166.0,0.0,3
56.0,0.0,4.0,0.0,2.0,150.0,2.0,2
42.0,1.0,1.0,0.0,2.0,178.0,2.0,0
59.0,1.0,1.0,0.0,2.0,145.0,0.0,0
60.0,0.0,4.0,0.0,2.0,161.0,0.0,1
63.0,0.0,2.0,0.0,0.0,179.0,2.0,0
42.0,1.0,3.0,1.0,0.0,194.0,0.0,0
66.0,1.0,2.0,0.0,0.0,120.0,3.0,2
54.0,1.0,2.0,0.0,2.0,195.0,1.0,1
69.0,1.0,3.0,0.0,2.0,146.0,3.0,2
50.0,1.0,3.0,0.0,0.0,163.0,0.0,0
51.0,1.0,4.0,0.0,0.0,122.0,3.0,3
62.0,0.0,4.0,1.0,0.0,106.0,3.0,2
68.0,0.0,3.0,0.0,2.0,115.0,0.0,0
67.0,1.0,4.0,0.0,2.0,125.0,2.0,3
69.0,1.0,1.0,1.0,2.0,131.0,1.0,0
45.0,0.0,4.0,0.0,2.0,152.0,0.0,0
50.0,0.0,2.0,0.0,0.0,162.0,0.0,0
59.0,1.0,1.0,0.0,2.0,125.0,0.0,1
50.0,0.0,4.0,0.0,2.0,159.0,0.0,0
64.0,0.0,4.0,0.0,0.0,154.0,0.0,0
57.0,1.0,3.0,1.0,0.0,173.0,1.0,0
64.0,0.0,3.0,0.0,0.0,133.0,0.0,0
43.0,1.0,4.0,0.0,0.0,161.0,0.0,0
45.0,1.0,4.0,0.0,2.0,147.0,3.0,3
58.0,1.0,4.0,0.0,2.0,130.0,2.0,3
50.0,1.0,4.0,0.0,2.0,126.0,0.0,3
55.0,1.0,2.0,0.0,0.0,155.0,0.0,0
62.0,0.0,4.0,0.0,0.0,154.0,0.0,1
37.0,0.0,3.0,0.0,0.0,170.0,0.0,0
38.0,1.0,1.0,0.0,0.0,182.0,0.0,4
41.0,1.0,3.0,0.0,2.0,168.0,0.0,0
66.0,0.0,4.0,1.0,0.0,165.0,2.0,3
52.0,1.0,4.0,0.0,0.0,160.0,1.0,1
56.0,1.0,1.0,0.0,2.0,162.0,0.0,0
46.0,0.0,2.0,0.0,0.0,172.0,0.0,0
46.0,0.0,4.0,0.0,2.0,152.0,0.0,0
64.0,0.0,4.0,0.0,0.0,122.0,2.0,0
59.0,1.0,4.0,0.0,2.0,182.0,0.0,0
41.0,0.0,3.0,0.0,2.0,172.0,0.0,0
54.0,0.0,3.0,0.0,2.0,167.0,0.0,0
39.0,0.0,3.0,0.0,0.0,179.0,0.0,0
53.0,1.0,4.0,0.0,0.0,95.0,2.0,3
63.0,0.0,4.0,0.0,0.0,169.0,2.0,1
34.0,0.0,2.0,0.0,0.0,192.0,0.0,0
47.0,1.0,4.0,0.0,0.0,143.0,0.0,0
67.0,0.0,3.0,0.0,0.0,172.0,1.0,0
54.0,1.0,4.0,0.0,2.0,108.0,1.0,3
66.0,1.0,4.0,0.0,2.0,132.0,1.0,2
52.0,0.0,3.0,0.0,2.0,169.0,0.0,0
55.0,0.0,4.0,0.0,1.0,117.0,0.0,2
49.0,1.0,3.0,0.0,2.0,126.0,3.0,1
74.0,0.0,2.0,0.0,2.0,121.0,1.0,0
54.0,0.0,3.0,0.0,0.0,163.0,1.0,0
54.0,1.0,4.0,0.0,2.0,116.0,2.0,3
56.0,1.0,4.0,1.0,2.0,103.0,0.0,2
46.0,1.0,4.0,0.0,2.0,144.0,0.0,1
49.0,0.0,2.0,0.0,0.0,162.0,0.0,0
42.0,1.0,2.0,0.0,0.0,162.0,0.0,0
41.0,1.0,2.0,0.0,0.0,153.0,0.0,0
41.0,0.0,2.0,0.0,0.0,163.0,0.0,0
49.0,0.0,4.0,0.0,0.0,163.0,0.0,0
61.0,1.0,1.0,0.0,0.0,145.0,2.0,2
60.0,0.0,3.0,1.0,0.0,96.0,0.0,0
67.0,1.0,4.0,0.0,0.0,71.0,0.0,2
58.0,1.0,4.0,0.0,0.0,156.0,1.0,2
47.0,1.0,4.0,0.0,2.0,118.0,1.0,1
52.0,1.0,4.0,0.0,0.0,168.0,2.0,3
62.0,1.0,2.0,1.0,2.0,140.0,0.0,0
57.0,1.0,4.0,0.0,0.0,126.0,0.0,0
58.0,1.0,4.0,0.0,0.0,105.0,1.0,1
64.0,1.0,4.0,0.0,0.0,105.0,1.0,0
51.0,0.0,3.0,0.0,2.0,157.0,0.0,0
43.0,1.0,4.0,0.0,0.0,181.0,0.0,0
42.0,0.0,3.0,0.0,0.0,173.0,0.0,0
67.0,0.0,4.0,0.0,0.0,142.0,2.0,0
76.0,0.0,3.0,0.0,1.0,116.0,0.0,0
70.0,1.0,2.0,0.0,2.0,143.0,0.0,0
57.0,1.0,2.0,0.0,0.0,141.0,0.0,1
44.0,0.0,3.0,0.0,0.0,149.0,1.0,0
58.0,0.0,2.0,1.0,2.0,152.0,2.0,3
60.0,0.0,1.0,0.0,0.0,171.0,0.0,0
44.0,1.0,3.0,0.0,0.0,169.0,0.0,0
61.0,1.0,4.0,0.0,2.0,125.0,1.0,4
42.0,1.0,4.0,0.0,0.0,125.0,0.0,2
52.0,1.0,4.0,1.0,0.0,156.0,0.0,2
59.0,1.0,3.0,1.0,0.0,134.0,1.0,2
40.0,1.0,4.0,0.0,0.0,181.0,0.0,1
42.0,1.0,3.0,0.0,0.0,150.0,0.0,0
61.0,1.0,4.0,0.0,2.0,138.0,1.0,1
66.0,1.0,4.0,0.0,2.0,138.0,0.0,0
46.0,1.0,4.0,0.0,0.0,120.0,2.0,2
71.0,0.0,4.0,0.0,0.0,125.0,0.0,0
59.0,1.0,1.0,0.0,0.0,162.0,2.0,1
64.0,1.0,1.0,0.0,2.0,155.0,0.0,0
66.0,0.0,3.0,0.0,2.0,152.0,1.0,0
39.0,0.0,3.0,0.0,0.0,152.0,0.0,0
57.0,1.0,2.0,0.0,2.0,164.0,1.0,1
58.0,0.0,4.0,0.0,0.0,131.0,0.0,0
57.0,1.0,4.0,0.0,0.0,143.0,1.0,2
47.0,1.0,3.0,0.0,0.0,179.0,0.0,0
55.0,0.0,4.0,0.0,1.0,130.0,1.0,3
35.0,1.0,2.0,0.0,0.0,174.0,0.0,0
61.0,1.0,4.0,0.0,0.0,161.0,1.0,2
58.0,1.0,4.0,0.0,1.0,140.0,3.0,4
58.0,0.0,4.0,1.0,2.0,146.0,2.0,2
56.0,1.0,2.0,0.0,2.0,163.0,0.0,0
56.0,1.0,2.0,0.0,0.0,169.0,0.0,0
67.0,1.0,3.0,0.0,2.0,150.0,0.0,1
55.0,0.0,2.0,0.0,0.0,166.0,0.0,0
44.0,1.0,4.0,0.0,0.0,144.0,0.0,2
63.0,1.0,4.0,0.0,2.0,144.0,2.0,2
63.0,0.0,4.0,0.0,0.0,136.0,0.0,1
41.0,1.0,2.0,0.0,0.0,182.0,0.0,0
59.0,1.0,4.0,1.0,2.0,90.0,2.0,3
57.0,0.0,4.0,0.0,0.0,123.0,0.0,1
45.0,1.0,1.0,0.0,0.0,132.0,0.0,1
68.0,1.0,4.0,1.0,0.0,141.0,2.0,2
57.0,1.0,4.0,0.0,0.0,115.0,1.0,3
57.0,0.0,2.0,0.0,2.0,174.0,1.0,1
66.0,0.0,3.0,0.0,2.0,152.0,1.0,0
39.0,0.0,3.0,0.0,0.0,152.0,0.0,0
57.0,1.0,2.0,0.0,2.0,164.0,1.0,1
58.0,0.0,4.0,0.0,0.0,131.0,0.0,0
57.0,1.0,4.0,0.0,0.0,143.0,1.0,2
47.0,1.0,3.0,0.0,0.0,179.0,0.0,0
55.0,0.0,4.0,0.0,1.0,130.0,1.0,3
35.0,1.0,2.0,0.0,0.0,174.0,0.0,0
61.0,1.0,4.0,0.0,0.0,161.0,1.0,2
58.0,1.0,4.0,0.0,1.0,140.0,3.0,4
46.0,1.0,4.0,0.0,0.0,120.0,2.0,2
71.0,0.0,4.0,0.0,0.0,125.0,0.0,0
59.0,1.0,1.0,0.0,0.0,162.0,2.0,1
64.0,1.0,1.0,0.0,2.0,155.0,0.0,0
66.0,0.0,3.0,0.0,2.0,152.0,1.0,0
39.0,0.0,3.0,0.0,0.0,152.0,0.0,0
57.0,1.0,2.0,0.0,2.0,164.0,1.0,1
58.0,0.0,4.0,0.0,0.0,131.0,0.0,0
57.0,1.0,4.0,0.0,0.0,143.0,1.0,2
47.0,1.0,3.0,0.0,0.0,179.0,0.0,0
55.0,0.0,4.0,0.0,1.0,130.0,1.0,3
35.0,1.0,2.0,0.0,0.0,174.0,0.0,0
61.0,1.0,4.0,0.0,0.0,161.0,1.0,2
58.0,1.0,4.0,0.0,1.0,140.0,3.0,4
58.0,0.0,4.0,1.0,2.0,146.0,2.0,2
39.0,0.0,3.0,0.0,0.0,179.0,0.0,0
53.0,1.0,4.0,0.0,0.0,95.0,2.0,3
63.0,0.0,4.0,0.0,0.0,169.0,2.0,1
34.0,0.0,2.0,0.0,0.0,192.0,0.0,0
47.0,1.0,4.0,0.0,0.0,143.0,0.0,0
67.0,0.0,3.0,0.0,0.0,172.0,1.0,0
54.0,1.0,4.0,0.0,2.0,108.0,1.0,3
66.0,1.0,4.0,0.0,2.0,132.0,1.0,2
52.0,0.0,3.0,0.0,2.0,169.0,0.0,0
55.0,0.0,4.0,0.0,1.0,117.0,0.0,2
49.0,1.0,3.0,0.0,2.0,126.0,3.0,1
74.0,0.0,2.0,0.0,2.0,121.0,1.0,0
54.0,0.0,3.0,0.0,0.0,163.0,1.0,0
54.0,1.0,4.0,0.0,2.0,116.0,2.0,3
56.0,1.0,4.0,1.0,2.0,103.0,0.0,2
46.0,1.0,4.0,0.0,2.0,144.0,0.0,1
49.0,0.0,2.0,0.0,0.0,162.0,0.0,0
42.0,1.0,2.0,0.0,0.0,162.0,0.0,0
45.0,1.0,4.0,0.0,2.0,185.0,0.0,0
34.0,1.0,1.0,0.0,2.0,174.0,0.0,0
57.0,0.0,4.0,0.0,2.0,159.0,1.0,0
71.0,0.0,3.0,1.0,2.0,130.0,1.0,0
49.0,1.0,3.0,0.0,0.0,139.0,3.0,3
54.0,1.0,2.0,0.0,0.0,156.0,0.0,0
59.0,1.0,4.0,0.0,0.0,162.0,1.0,2
57.0,1.0,3.0,0.0,2.0,150.0,1.0,1
61.0,1.0,4.0,0.0,0.0,140.0,1.0,2
39.0,1.0,4.0,0.0,0.0,140.0,0.0,3
61.0,0.0,4.0,0.0,2.0,146.0,0.0,1
56.0,1.0,4.0,1.0,2.0,144.0,1.0,1
52.0,1.0,1.0,0.0,2.0,190.0,0.0,0
43.0,0.0,4.0,1.0,2.0,136.0,0.0,2
67.0,1.0,4.0,0.0,2.0,108.0,3.0,2
67.0,1.0,4.0,0.0,2.0,129.0,2.0,1
37.0,1.0,3.0,0.0,0.0,187.0,0.0,0
41.0,0.0,2.0,0.0,2.0,172.0,0.0,0
56.0,1.0,2.0,0.0,0.0,178.0,0.0,0
62.0,0.0,4.0,0.0,2.0,160.0,2.0,3
57.0,0.0,4.0,0.0,0.0,163.0,0.0,0
63.0,1.0,4.0,0.0,2.0,147.0,1.0,2
53.0,1.0,4.0,1.0,2.0,155.0,0.0,1
57.0,1.0,4.0,0.0,0.0,148.0,0.0,0
56.0,0.0,2.0,0.0,2.0,153.0,0.0,0
56.0,1.0,3.0,1.0,2.0,142.0,1.0,2
44.0,1.0,2.0,0.0,0.0,173.0,0.0,0
52.0,1.0,3.0,1.0,0.0,162.0,0.0,0
57.0,1.0,3.0,0.0,0.0,174.0,0.0,0
48.0,1.0,2.0,0.0,0.0,168.0,0.0,1
54.0,1.0,4.0,0.0,0.0,160.0,0.0,0
48.0,0.0,3.0,0.0,0.0,139.0,0.0,0
50.0,1.0,2.0,0.0,0.0,160.0,0.0,0
54.0,0.0,2.0,0.0,0.0,150.0,1.0,0
54.0,0.0,2.0,0.0,1.0,155.0,1.0,0
54.0,0.0,2.0,0.0,0.0,130.0,1.0,0
54.0,0.0,2.0,0.0,0.0,130.0,1.0,0
54.0,1.0,1.0,0.0,0.0,137.0,1.0,0
54.0,1.0,2.0,0.0,0.0,142.0,1.0,0
54.0,1.0,2.0,0.0,0.0,154.0,1.0,0
54.0,1.0,2.0,0.0,0.0,110.0,1.0,0
54.0,1.0,2.0,0.0,1.0,130.0,1.0,0
59.0,1.0,4.0,0.0,0.0,140.0,0.0,0
47.0,1.0,4.0,0.0,0.0,98.0,0.0,1
56.0,1.0,4.0,0.0,0.0,120.0,0.0,1
59.0,1.0,4.0,0.0,1.0,131.0,0.0,0
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are training your model with normalized data but predicting on data that is not normalized. `X_test` is normalized data so the predictions on it are as expected. `dummyTest` is not normalized. If you normalize the `dummyTest` variable before feeding it to your neural network like so:

```
dummyTest[0] -= mean
dummyTest[0] /= std
```

You will receive the expected output(`1`)

Comment: Hi Ali, thank you for your quick response. I have only shown snippets of our code and dataset. I think my full code and dataset has something that might be the culprit but I'm not sure. I'm currently uploading both. Formatting is weird.

Comment: Hi Ali, I uploaded both the full code and dataset. I have no idea what is going on and am pretty desperate.

Comment: I've edited the answer to your post, please mark it as accepted if it answers your question!

Comment: Hi Ali, thank you very much for your help! This was the problem we had.